# Dividing the Circle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

Here's a neat geometrical puzzle I was once shown

Is it possible to divide a circle into a finite number of congruent parts some of which don't touch the center?

Clarification:

Find a shape for a tile such that a certain number of tiles of that shape will fit completely and with no overlap inside a circle. Additionally at least one the the tiles can't touch the center of the circle

Comment: I believe this is a pure math-geometry question

Comment: I fixed the tags

Comment: I mean question is not belong here. it should be in Math.SE - But it is only MY opinion

Comment: It is there already http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-o with a different solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible like so:

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the correct answer. I found a similar but different one